# Special characters showing invalid

Tags: php, html, compression

I am using a way to compress HTML on fly. Below is the function

```
function compress_page($buffer) {
    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s', /*strip whitespaces after tags, except space*/
        '/[^\S ]+\</s', /*strip whitespaces before tags, except space*/
        '/(\s)+/s',  /*shorten multiple whitespace sequences*/
    );
    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1',
    );
    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
```

function is working but the problem is, after implement this, germam characters are not showing anymore. They are showing like  "�". Can you please help me to find problem.
I tried other ways to minify HTML but get same proble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research, I found this solution. This will minify full html in one line.

```
function pt_html_minyfy_finish( $html )  {
  $html = preg_replace('/<!--(?!s*(?:[if [^]]+]|!|>))(?:(?!-->).)*-->/s', '', $html);
  $html = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t"), '', $html);
  while ( stristr($html, '  '))
     $html = str_replace('  ', ' ', $html);
 return $html;
}
```

Hope this will help someone!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's happen because you are not add Unicode flag support to regex.

Anyway I write a code to minified:

```
function sanitize_output($buffer, $type = null) {

        $search = array(
            '/\>[^\S ]+/s',     // strip whitespaces after tags, except space
            '/[^\S ]+\</s',     // strip whitespaces before tags, except space
            '/(\s)+/s',         // shorten multiple whitespace sequences
            '/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/', // Remove HTML comments
            '#/\*(.|\s)*\*/#Uu' // Remove JS comments
        );

        $replace = array(
            '>',
            '<',
            ' ',
            '',
            ''
        );


        if( $type == 'html' ){
            // Remove quets of attributs
            $search[] = '#(\w+=)(?:"|\')((\S|\.|\-|/|_|\(|\)|\w){1,8})(?:"|\')#u';
            $replace[] = '$1$2';

            // Remove spaces beetween tags
            $search[] = '#(>)\s+(<)#mu';
            $replace[] = '$1$2';
        }

        $buffer = str_replace( PHP_EOL, '', preg_replace( $search, $replace, $buffer ) );

        return $buffer;
    }
```

Comment: @DavinderKumar Give me the html code lines above the � pls.